# Request scoped bean is always available when running code outside of request scope in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Stuck on this thing in Spring 4, probably the same will be for 5.

So, what I have:

1. Spring Boot 1.5 web app
2. Request scoped bean:

```
  @RequestScope
  @Component
  public class APIAction { ... }
```

3. Code which accesses this component from threads related or not related to webrequest:

```
  private final ObjectProvider<APIAction> apiAction;

  apiAction.getIfAvailable()...
```

4. When it runs in Thread bounded to web request everything is fine. But when I invoke it from daemon thread I expect to get `null`, exception or something else. Instead I'm receiving some proxy object which can't be tested for null, or any kind of state indicating that bean is really available. If I'll try to invoke any bean method, I'll get exception finally saying accessing to bean outside of thread bounded to web request.

So the question is, am I using it wrong? Right now, I'm checking request scope before accessing to bean by invoking this: `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null`, which is really ugly, and I need all the time to tell people why they should use it like this.

And bonus question, is it possible actually to instantiate that bean in threads without request bound?

Comment: I am bit confused, you are saying "I'm checking request scope before accessing to bean by invoking this: RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null" is that in your daemon thread ? If so, are you relying on the random chance where the request will not be null(when the user makes the request) and at the same point your daemon thread will kick in ?

Comment: It's not a random case. I'm trying to reuse some code for scheduled jobs and rest controllers. So for rest api I have request scoped bean which holds some cache during processing of request. And I'm looking for a way how to simplify current code without checking all the time (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can't use `ObjectProvider.getIfAvailable()` to check if in request scope.

Use `if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null)` instead.

---

As the javadoc of [`ObjectProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) says:

> A variant of [`ObjectFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html) designed specifically for injection points, allowing for programmatic optionality and lenient not-unique handling.

For singleton beans, `ObjectProvider<APIAction>` is an alternative to `@Autowired(required = false) List<APIAction>` with methods that better represent the purpose.

For prototype beans, it allows the on-demand creation of the prototype, including optional constructor arguments.

However, it's all about the *existence* of the bean, i.e. about whether the bean has been registered (and how many). Any `@Component` (or other) annotated class is registered by the component scanning, regardless of the bean *scope*.

The `@RequestScope` bean exists, so the code could be changed to `@Autowired private final APIAction apiAction;`, and it would always be non-null.

The fact that the object referred to by `apiAction` is a proxy that will apply method calls to different instances depending the the request context is besides the point.

When you call an `APIAction` method, you will get an `IllegalStateException` saying:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Internally, a [`@RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html) annotated class has a `Scope` of type [`RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.html), and the javadoc says:

> Relies on a thread-bound [`RequestAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html) instance.

It does this by calling [`RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#currentRequestAttributes--), which throws the above exception.

**Solution:** To check if you are in a request context, call [`RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes--) and check for `null` return value.

Comment: OK, seems like a wrapping retrieval of request scoped bean in another service is the only way to hide this check: RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() ! = null

Comment: this is [addressed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24822) in Spring 5.3+